# What a priori is the domain and codomain of a function?

Tags: functions, soft-question, relations

Naturally the domain of discourse dictates some upper bounds: for example, if working in ‘*real* analysis’ then the domain and likewise the codomain ought to be constrained to ℝ. But absent context outside of statement(s) of the function as defined, what determines the maximal spaces respectively from which inputs  can be drawn (source) and outputs to be sent (target)?

The image of the domain (often termed the range) can exist only where corresponding ordinates from pre-image are defined, and versa‐vice. But besides denying denominator equal to zero (especially when directly underneath a non‑zero fixed numerator) in most discourses, Iʼm not sure about any steadfast rules.. let alone a heuristic for deciding which overarching discourse-domain that the function (or other type of relation) and thus its domain ⩖ codomain (supersets respectively of preimage ⩖ image, possibly improper) is meant to, or perhaps must, belong to. Do particular operations or types⧸roles of non‑variable values preclude certain target or source ֊pools?

Comment: In real analysis, the domain and codomain can be $\mathbb{R}^n$. Nothing determines what a domain and codomain should be, they can be any sets you want. For example, in complex analysis you can extend lots of nice $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ functions to $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ functions. You use functions as they are useful and natural, and it's usually obvious based on context.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews. So a function could be defined, or necessarily conforming to, something like ℝ^→ℝ^? What about ℂ^→ℝ^ where n=/=m? Need  and  be fixed?  What does such a function look like, to require arbitrary-(whole)dimensional domain or codomain?

Comment: Specifying domain and codomain is part of a rigorous definition of any function. Unfortunately, the current curriculum at least in some places suggests otherwise by asking students to *find* a domain, whereby they actually mean to find something like "the largest possible domain in $\mathbb R$".

Comment: By the way, some of your typesetting is idiosyncratic, and in the Latin phrase "a priori", like in all Latin, there is no accent on the a.

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg    It is also of French origin where the diacritic is used, and creates a distinct lexeme in English from the indefinite article. Syrictly speaking however it is a hypercorrection, but one that I personally approve-of for the reason stated, along with "maté" in 'yerba maté' for thr same reason (which arguably isn't an over-correction because of more than one dialect/language influencing it's usage/evolution).  What typesetting is errant?

Comment: Thomas Andrews designed the Titanic. Also, it should be noted in line with Torsten's comment that some definitions of function only include range, not codomain, so any set containing the range has an equal claim to being the codomain. But including explicit codomains is very useful for reasons that will become apparent the more mathematics you do.

Comment: I get weird symbols near the end of your question between "domain" and "codomain", then again between "preimage" and "image", then an empty box between "types" and "roles", and another strange symbol right in front of the last word "pools" (?). Also, although I see a symbol $\mathbb R$, it seems you did not create it using MathJax. Please note that this site uses MathJax, and to make your question well-received, so should you.